# How can sync focuse on OutlinedTextField with use trailingIcon ? - Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my case, I am using the trailingIcon in the OutlinedTextField to extend the DropdownMenu. If used, click on the trailingIcon - the DropdownMenu will be expanded, but the OutlinedTextField will not focus. Also, when using click OutlinedTextField - the DropdownMenu will not expand, but the OutlinedTextField will be focused.

```
@Composable
fun DownMenuTextField(
    @StringRes titleId: Int,
    selectedText: String,
    suggestions: List<String>,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val icon = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.ArrowDropUp else Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown

    Column {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = selectedText,
            readOnly = true,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                },
            label = {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(titleId),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                    )
                }
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(icon, "contentDescription",
                    Modifier.focusable(false)
                    .clickable { expanded = !expanded })
            }
        )

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
        ) {
            suggestions.forEach { label ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    onValueChange(label)
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on click trailingIcon:

[image: on click trailingIcon]

on click OutlinedTextField:

[image: on click OutlinedTextField]

How to do when user clicks on trailingIcon or OutlinedTextField - always OutlinedTextField will be focused and DropdownMenu will be expanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the dropdown menu after `TextField` gets focus, the `onFocusChanged` modifier is good for this.

Then in `onDismissRequest` or when the item is selected, you can clear focus with `LocalFocusManager`.

One remark off-topic to your question. I advise you to always use `modifier` as the last argument: in this case you don't need to add a comma at the end, which makes it easier to add new/remove unnecessary modifiers

```kotlin
val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }
val icon = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.ArrowDropUp else Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

Column {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = selectedOption,
        readOnly = true,
        onValueChange = {},
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(icon, null)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onFocusChanged {
                expanded = it.isFocused
            }
    )

    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        options.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedOption = label
                expanded = false
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Philip , focusManager is really work!

Comment: One particular problem with this implementation is the use of a physical keyboard. A particular app I work on that uses a similar implementation has a requirement to support bluetooth keyboards and tabbing through a large from.   It sort of breaks the flow of the "tab" by clearing focus like this.