# How to prevent Jetpack Compose ExposedDropdownMenuBox from showing menu when scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use Jetpack Compose's ExposedDropdownMenuBox but I can't prevent it from showing the menu when scrolling.

For example, here's the code to replicate this problem:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        repeat(20){
                            ExposedDropdownMenuSample()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[ExposedDropdownMenuSample](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/samples/ExposedDropdownMenuSamples.kt) was taken from the official samples.

[This is a GIF showing the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzXoT.gif)

How can I prevent this from happening?

This code is using compose version **1.1.0-rc01**.

Comment: I don't see you doing anything wrong here, I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) it to the issue tracker. Until it's fixed, you can check out on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69144914/3585796)

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov. I will report it and use your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, please give it an up-vote =)

Comment: I can't upvote... too new I think?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that =) you need 15 ratings.

Answer (score 2):

edit: now it doesn't swallow fling-motion as reported by m.reiter

I was able to fix this with this ugly hack:

```
private fun Modifier.cancelOnExpandedChangeIfScrolling(cancelNext: () -> Unit) = pointerInput(Unit) {
    forEachGesture {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                var event: PointerEvent
                var startPosition = Offset.Unspecified
                var cancel = false

                do {
                    event = awaitPointerEvent(PointerEventPass.Initial)
                    if (event.changes.any()) {
                        if (startPosition == Offset.Unspecified) {
                            startPosition = event.changes.first().position
                        }

                        val distance =
                            startPosition.minus(event.changes.last().position).getDistance()
                        cancel = distance > 10f || cancel
                    }
                } while (!event.changes.all { it.changedToUp() })

                if (cancel) {
                    cancelNext.invoke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then add it to the `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` like:

```
var cancelNextExpandedChange by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } //this is to prevent fling motion from being swallowed
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
        if (!cancelNextExpandedChange) expanded = !expanded
        cancelNextExpandedChange = false
    }, modifier = Modifier.cancelOnExpandedChangeIfScrolling() { cancelNextExpandedChange = true }
)
```

So it basically checks if there was a drag for more than ***10 pixels?*** and if true, invokes the callback that sets `cancelNextExpandedChange` to `true` so it will skip the next `onExpandedChange`.

10 is just a magic number that worked well for my tests, but it seems to be too low for a high res screen device. I'm sure there's a better way to calculate this number... Maybe someone more experienced can help with this until we have a proper fix?

Comment: Fling-Motion is swallowed, but otherwise this is working pretty nicely :)

Comment: @m.reiter fixed =)

Comment: Works nicely now :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was reported in:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212091796

and fixed in androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly less hacky workaround:

You get the info whether a scrolling is in progress from the scroll-state of the Column.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
val isScrolling = scrollState.isScrollInProgress

Column(
  modifier = Modifier
    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
    .verticalScroll(scrollState),
    ...
) ...
```

In the *ExposedDropdownMenuBox* you can then change the listener to

```
onExpandedChange = {
  expanded = !expanded && !isScrolling
},
```

=> The dropdown is never opened while scrolling. It is also automatically closed as soon as you start scrolling in the main-column. However scrolling inside the dropdown is possible.
Of course you can also cahnge it to something like

```
expanded = if (isScrolling) expanded else !expanded
```

To just leave everything like it is while scrolling